# Edit GridView text

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

How can I change `select` text in a GridView which is generated visually in MS Visual Studio, I mean how to change the surrounded text in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the  `SelectText` property in the `asp:CommandField` tag.

Try This:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="yourtext here" />
```